# Get TinyMCE to use full image url instead of relative one (Umbraco 4.0.3)

Tags: url, tinymce, umbraco

I know this question has been asked (and answered) before, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me.

I've set the following in the tinyMceConfig.config:

```
<config key="relative_urls">false</config>

<config key="convert_urls">false</config>

<config key="remove_script_host">false</config>
```

And I've included the following in my tinyMCE.init script:

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
convert_urls : false,
```

But still when I try to insert an image it only uses the relative url, and when I type in the full URL, it trims it.

This is for a newsletter, so I need to have absolute links. Any other suggestions, anyone?

I'm using Umbraco v4.0.3, and Tiny MCE 3

Answer (score 3):

You should also disable `remove_script_host`. The full configs that work for me look like this:

`relative_urls: false,`

`convert_urls: false,`

`remove_script_host : false,`